# configurationmanger not working in vs2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, configuration, web-config, app-config

I am trying to read configuration file using

> **ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings**

but it is not available in vs2010.

**ConfigurationSettings** doesn't read *`connectionstring`* section.

Can anyone provide some help on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration`.